How to make clicking on an application icon immediately switch that application in Windows the same was it works in macOS?
In Windows if you click on the icon of an application in the Taskbar (the footer area of the operating syste), Windows shows thumbnails of all the open windows of that application. To switch to the application you have to click again on the specific window that is shown.
On macOS, if you click on an icon of an application you immediately switch to that application and all windows of that application are shown (the last one focused is shown on top).
How do I get Windows to switch to the application immediately when I click on the application icon?

Update: I noticed if I clicked on the application icon and held down Ctrl it switches to the application immediately.
This can serve as a workaround but it was mentioned in the comments there is or may be a setting for this "How to show or group task bar items". I can't find that setting anywhere.
To test, open two or three projects in Visual Studio Code (vscode). You'll see it displays three windows in small boxes above the taskbar.

AFAIK, you'd have to disable Taskbar icon grouping, which would then create an icon for each individual instance of the application.

OK. I'll look for that. FYI I noticed if I clicked on the application icon and held down CTRL it switches to the icon.

Looking in personalization > taskbar settings, I don't see any options for taskbar icon grouping. When searching by "taskbar" there is an search result that says, "Choose how to group similar windows" but that goes back to the taskbar settings page.

@JoepvanSteen, I think you may be working with a program that has multiple windows but that they are part of a single "instance", like for example, if you dragged panels out of visual studios main window. if you then open a second instance of visual studio because you need to have two different solutions loaded, then clicking on the VS icon in your task bar will "prompt" you to select which of the two Vs instance you want to bring to the foreground. Personally I would not like it if I clicked on my firefox icon, and all 6 firefox windows I have open jumped to the front.

@JoepvanSteen I'll add an answer but it would be a hack because I want to turn the feature off.

If I hold down CTRL while clicking on an icon it brings one of the windows to the front rather than displaying window previews. It's not the solution I'm looking for but it works as a workaround.
